# Check if PropertyInfo is interface implementation

Tags: c#, reflection

What is the correct way to check that a given property info is an implementation of a property from an interface?

There is a class `InterfaceMap` that solve this problem for methods. But for properties, it provides two separate mappings for getter and setter and there still remains a problem to match those with the corresponding interface methods.

```cs
public interface IA
{
    int X { get; set; }
}

public interface IB
{
    int X { get; set; }
}

public class C : IA, IB
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    int IB.X { get; set; }
}

public PropertyInfo GetProperty<TClass, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> getProperty)
{
    return (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)getProperty.Body).Member;
}

[Test]
public void Check()
{
    var aProperty = GetProperty((IA x) => x.X);
    var bProperty = GetProperty((IB x) => x.X);
    var cPropertyA = GetProperty((C x) => x.X);
    var cPropertyB = GetProperty((C x) => ((IB)x).X);

    CompareProperties(cPropertyA, aProperty); // True
    CompareProperties(cPropertyA, bProperty); // False
    CompareProperties(cPropertyB, aProperty); // False
    CompareProperties(cPropertyB, bProperty); // True
}

private bool CompareProperties(PropertyInfo classProperty, PropertyInfo interfaceProperty)
{
    // TODO implement 
}
```

Comment: You may have to consider the getters and setters separately. An interface requiring only a getter may be implemented by a public property with both getter and setter.

Comment: The problem is that having the getter for the class-property and the getter for the interface-property there is no way to properly compare them for equality. A simple call to `Equals` returns `false` since they have different declaring types.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Even if the interface property specifies only a getter and the class implementation has both getter and setter the problem still remains: how to check that this specific property implements that interface.

Answer (score 1):

From a given [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo), you can use the [`GetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getmethod) and [`SetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setmethod) properties to access the [`MethodInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo) of the getter and setter, respectively.

Thus, it should be possible to compare those in a little helper method:

```
private static bool MethodsImplements(InterfaceMap interfaceMap,
    MethodInfo interfaceMethod, MethodInfo classMethod)
{
    var implIndex = Array.IndexOf(interfaceMap.InterfaceMethods, interfaceMethod);
    return interfaceMethod == interfaceMap.TargetMethods[implIndex];
}
```

This can then be used as follows to fulfil your desired method:

```
var interfaceType = interfaceProperty.DeclaringType;
var interfaceMap = classProperty.DeclaringType.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceType);

var gettersMatch = classProperty.CanRead && interfaceProperty.CanRead
    && MethodImplements(interfaceMap, interfaceProperty.GetMethod, classProperty.GetMethod);

var settersMatch = classProperty.CanWrite && interfaceProperty.CanWrite
    && MethodImplements(interfaceMap, interfaceProperty.SetMethod, classProperty.SetMethod);
```

Then, return `gettersMatch || settersMatch`, as the interface property may have only a getter or only a setter.